# Синтаксическая ошибка при обновлении таблицы

Tags: mysql, update

Я пытаюсь обновить таблицу скриптом:

```
USE `event`;

UPDATE TABLE `events_log` SET `users_id` = 
(SELECT `id` FROM `users_cash`.`users` 
WHERE `users_cash`.`users`.`login` LIKE 
(
SELECT `context_data` FROM `event`.`events_log`)
);
```

Но получаю ошибку:

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'table `events_log` set `users_id` = (select `id`
>   from `users_cash`.`users` where' at line 1

Таблица `events_log` находится в базе данных `event`:

```
CREATE TABLE `events_log` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `events_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `context_data` text,
  `users_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_events_log` (`events_id`),
  KEY `fk_events_log_users_id` (`users_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_events_log` FOREIGN KEY (`events_id`) REFERENCES `events` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_events_log_users_id` FOREIGN KEY (`users_id`) REFERENCES `users_cash`.`users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=151270 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251
```

а таблица `users` находится в базе данных `users_cash`:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `login` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=63 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 CHECKSUM=1 DELAY_KEY_WRITE=1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

Я хочу сделать поле `event`.`events_log`.`users_id` равным полю `users_cash`.`users`.`id`, причём выбираю это `id` по соответствию полей `users_cash`.`users`.`login` и `event`.`events_log`.`context_data`.
Почему происходит ошибка, и как написать правильный запрос для этого обновления?

Comment: UPDATE без TABLE напишите

Comment: @ilyaplot, да, точно, спасибо! не заметила) оформите как ответ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE`events_log` SET `users_id` = 
(SELECT `id` FROM `users_cash`.`users` 
WHERE `users_cash`.`users`.`login` LIKE 
(
SELECT `context_data` FROM `event`.`events_log`)
);
```

Нужно просто убрать TABLE из запроса.